# php - Manipulating text file will bug when overloaded?

Tags: php, fwrite

I have a javascript web app that is calling a php script each time it recieves an event from the websocket (between 1 to 8 times each second, no specific interval).

I want to save this information (json) into a text file to be able to be able to use it for later purposes.

```
<?php
$file = '../backtests/' . $_POST['name'] . '.txt';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $to_add = '[' . $_POST['_data'] . ']';
}
else {
 $to_add = ',' . $_POST['_data'] . ']'; 
}

$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file");

$stat = fstat($fh);
ftruncate($fh, $stat['size']-1);
fwrite($fh, $to_add);
fclose($fh); 

?>
```

Ok so the problem is, at the beggining the it is working, but after the file is getting 40-50 kb of text, it's getting corrupted, and php will start writing at the wrong part of the file, and so corrupting it.

I am not sure what causes this but I guess it's because the file is growing and php takes more and more time to edit it?

What other solution could I use?

Thank you.

Comment: I hope this is just a simplified example for illustration purposes because the security hole is blatant. In any case, the only sensible way to accomplish concurrent data storage is using a proper database engine.

Comment: It is a personal web app not intended to be public, I will run it on my local server only. So there is not way for storing each "log" on a different file, database would be less adapted to what I am trying to do...

Comment: I think you have identified the issue yourself - as the file grows PHP will take longer to process the file - I agree with Alvaro that a db would be a better solution so how frequently do you need to process the data within the file?

Comment: @RamRaider each time I recieve the information from the web socket, so about 1 to 8 times each second

Comment: `"I want to save this information (json) into a text file to be able to be able to use it for later purposes."` - this is what I meant - later?? the file is being written 1-8 times per second so are you meaning that you are also processing it at that same rate or later?

Comment: This is a large part of what databases are designed to handle: concurrent access. If you don't want to use a database for whatever reason, you'll have to worry about that problem yourself. See the duplicate.

Comment: Even if it's just an internal script and you'll never ever deploy it to a public facing server, nor lend your computer to anyway else, a simple spelling typo while testing can get any random file wiped out inadvertently. Security checks are not just about Russian hackers ;-)

Comment: @RamRaider No, basicly this will log on the text file all the informations recieved, and use it after everything needed is backed-up

Comment: It sounds like you basically want to dump a bunch of semi-rapidly incoming information as quickly as possible and then post-process it later. Then the dumping to file should be as quick as possible and you shouldn't worry about creating any particular data format in that file; that can all be post-processed later. You should probably simply append to the file with a newline or other safe separator character instead of trying to create some sort of array format. You'll still have to worry about locking the file though.

Comment: Or, if @deceze is right, just create brand new files each time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your local server *might be* running several PHP scripts at the same time, overwriting each other's data.

You have to use a custom locking mechanism -too complicated- or a local database, which takes care of these issues. Give [Sqlite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php) or [Redis](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-redis-in-php) a try; it's easier than it seems.